# Help testing special file in `/sys/class/net/`

Tags: bash, networking, files

### Background

I am managing a cellular interface. I have a `bash` script that is testing the interface. In question is the file located at `/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier` where `wwan1` is an **unconfigured** interface.

This is obviously a special file, but I am unsure how to correctly test it in a bash script. See below...

Consider the following:

```
file /sys/class/net/wwan0/carrier # a good interface
/sys/class/net/wwan0/carrier: ASCII text

file /sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier # an unconfigured interface
/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier: ERROR: cannot read `/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier' (Invalid argument)
```

Some `cat` data:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wwan0/carrier # good interface
1

$ cat /sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier # unconfigured
cat: /sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier: Invalid argument
```

This error from `cat` is the problem.

The file located at `/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier` is reported by `ls` however:

```
$ cd /sys/class/net/wwan1
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    0 Dec 27 17:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 27 17:36 ..
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 addr_assign_type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 address
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 addr_len
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 broadcast
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:57 carrier
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 28 20:24 device -> ../../../1-1:1.10
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 dev_id
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 dormant
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 duplex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 flags
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 ifalias
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 ifindex
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 iflink
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 link_mode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 mtu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 netdev_group
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:57 operstate
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Dec 28 20:24 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 speed
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Dec 28 20:24 statistics
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 27 17:36 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/net
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 tx_queue_len
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 20:24 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 27 17:36 uevent
```

### The Problem

I am testing a variety of possible interface configurations and problems in a bash script. One of which is that the interface is unconfigured. I am probing `/sys` because I have found the output of `ifconfig` and `ip` to be unreliable.

### My Question

How can I test the value of the file `/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier` in a `bash` `if` statement (the file itself being unreadable but present, i.e. this is an **unconfigured** interface? Here's what I have tried:

```
if [[ -e "/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier" ]]; then
    echo "Good"
else
    echo "Bad"
fi
```

I have also used the tests `-b, -c, -f` all of which fail to be able to distinguish between the 'readable' state of this file in `/sys/class/net/wwan1/` - the 'bad' file, and `/sys/class/net/wwan0/` - the 'good' file.

### Edit

The `-r` and `-s` tests reports good in both cases, which is a problem since `cat` will fail in the first case.

### Edit `stat` output

```
$ stat /sys/class/net/wwan0/carrier
  File: `/sys/class/net/wwan0/carrier'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fh/15d  Inode: 5657        Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-12-28 17:01:06.976418548 +0000
Modify: 2015-12-28 17:01:06.976418548 +0000
Change: 2015-12-28 17:01:06.976418548 +0000
 Birth: -
```

and

```
$ stat /sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier
  File: `/sys/class/net/wwan1/carrier'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fh/15d  Inode: 6181        Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-12-28 18:57:37.876419704 +0000
Modify: 2015-12-28 18:57:37.876419704 +0000
Change: 2015-12-28 18:57:37.876419704 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: @drewbenn Yes it is non-zero on a failed read. I think I may end up just going with that if I cannot distinguish between a valid using `test`

Comment: @jimmij that is correct. I want to know can I see this with `test` or not

Comment: @jimmij see edits

Comment: `/sys` being a virtual file system, I'd say there's no way you can deduce what state `carrier` is in unless you actually read the file, not just file metadata. And if you do try to read it, you might as well use `cat` or `file` and their exit codes.

Comment: You should just cat the file and check the exit status , if it is 0 then the interface is good , otherwise bad.

Answer (score 2):

I have experimented with my WiFi interface which also have the `carrier` pseudo file :`/sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier`. (note: I have used `nmtui` to enable/disable Wireless networks).

It seems there are three states:

- `./carrier` not readable (for instance when the interface is disabled in Network Manager).
- `./carrier` contain "1" (when the interface is activated and it is connected to a WiFi network)
- `./carrier` contain "0" (when the interface is activated and it is **not** connected to a WiFi network)

```
  if ! cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier > /dev/null; then
    echo "Not connected to any network"
  elif [ "$(head -c1 /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier)" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Connected to a wireless network"
  elif [ "$(head -c1 /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Not connected to a wireless network"
  else
    echo "Unknown/Unhandled state"
  fi
```